# Override MenuStrip.Items.Add()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, overriding, menustrip

I have create a database tables which holds all the menu with a self join to make it like  Level0 -> Level1 -> Level2 .....etc. Populating these records in a MenuStrip required a huge amount of code so i would like to encapsulate all this code on Server Control, i would like to create a server control that overrid the method MenuStrip.Items.Add() and transfer all my code there but i can't seem to find it. The only thing available to override is ToolStripItemCollection, is there Any soultion ?

Comment: It is not a virtual method, you can't override it.  Just put this in a separate source file with a method that takes or returns a MenuStrip.  The designer is useless anyway with this approach so there's no loss of functionality.  Putting UI in a dbase is very rarely worth the hassle btw.